# Postgresql - Select Count of 'votes' but only including the latest

Tags: postgresql

I've been staring at this for 20 minutes and can't wrap my head around it.  I've done it before, I just don't remember in which project ( so i can reference code ).

I have a table as such:

```
votes [table]
  id - serial , primary
  useraccount_id - id
  object_id - id
  vote - int
  timestamp_vote - timestamp
```

I need to be able to select the current total of votes for any one object.

However - this table acts as a 'timeline' view as well. note that i'm using a sequence as an id column.  there may be multiple records for useraccount_id + object_id

Unfortunately, this is not what i need:

```
SELECT 
   vote , count(vote)
FROM 
   votes
WHERE
   object_id = 161 
GROUP BY 
   vote ;
```

i know need to use a subquery and distinct, and an 'order by timestamp desc' , to limit to the latest vote by a given user.  i just can't remember how to string that SELECT together.

-- adding sample data --

Sample Data

```
 id | object_id  | useraccount_id |     timestamp_created      | vote 
----+------------+----------------+----------------------------+------------
  2 |        153 |             57 | 2012-12-11 18:37:20.421013 |    1
  3 |        153 |             57 | 2012-12-11 18:48:39.963748 |    2
  4 |        153 |             57 | 2012-12-11 18:48:42.869945 |    3
  5 |        153 |             57 | 2012-12-11 18:48:48.991617 |    1
  6 |        153 |             57 | 2012-12-11 19:34:26.701351 |    2
  7 |        153 |             57 | 2012-12-11 19:35:52.449031 |    3
  8 |        153 |             57 | 2012-12-11 19:35:52.986822 |    1
  9 |        153 |             57 | 2012-12-11 19:35:53.850291 |    2
 10 |        153 |             58 | 2012-12-11 19:35:55.884202 |    3
 12 |        153 |             58 | 2012-12-11 19:35:56.803337 |    1
 13 |        153 |             59 | 2012-12-11 19:37:04.563519 |    3
 15 |        153 |             60 | 2012-12-11 19:37:40.618324 |    3
 16 |        153 |             61 | 2012-12-11 19:37:40.618324 |    3
 17 |        153 |             62 | 2012-12-11 19:37:40.618324 |    3
 18 |        153 |             63 | 2012-12-11 19:37:40.618324 |    2
```

The expected output is:

```
vote | count
-----+------
1    | 1        # user 58 cast a vote of `3` , then `1`.  only the latest vote of `1` counted.
2    | 2        # user 57 switched votes many times. only their last vote of `2` counted. user 63 cast a vote of `2` as well.
3    | 4        # users 59,60,61,62 all voted `3`
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data and expected results. Best in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: The sample output includes more than just object_id = 161. So it does not match your first query. You might want to align those two things

Comment: thanks. i just noted that too and fixed it.

Comment: Another problem - in the table definition you have `vote - boolean`, and then `vote = 1, 2, 3 ...` in example.

Comment: Thanks @IgorRomanchenko ; The column was a boolean when I posted the question. I changed it an integer because I decided to cache votes ( using NULL as a conscious vote abstention would have made the caching layer think no vote was cast ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (useraccount_id, object_id) 
       vote, 
       timestamp_vote,
       useraccount_id,
       object_id
FROM votes
WHERE object_id = 161 -- your filter here
ORDER BY useraccount_id, object_id, timestamp_vote DESC
```

It will give you the last vote for every `(useraccount_id, object_id)`.

Then:

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN vote THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as true_vote_sum,
       SUM (CASE WHEN vote THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as false_vote_sum
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (useraccount_id, object_id) 
             vote
      FROM votes
      WHERE object_id = 161 -- your filter here
      ORDER BY useraccount_id, object_id, timestamp_vote DESC)
```

To get the count of the votes.

Details: [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html), [CASE WHEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html)

Comment: Thanks.  You helped me find what i wanted -- 



SELECT vote , count( vote ) FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (useraccount_id, object_id) 
     vote, 
     timestamp_created,
     useraccount_id,
     object_id
 FROM id
 WHERE object_id = ? 
 ORDER BY useraccount_id, object_id, timestamp_created DESC
) AS sq1 GROUP BY vote ;

Comment: ... and something like your query is what I should have wanted in the first place.  having everything in a single row is much more extensible.  double thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select vote, 
       count(vote) as cnt
from (
   select vote, 
          row_number() over (partition by vote order by timestamp_created desc) as rn
   from votes
)
where rn = 1
group by vote;
```

Comment: thanks. i'll look into partition and windowing when I have time.  i'm not sure how to adapt that query to my exact needs - but it looks like a better approach.